# Connect to PEAP secured (MSCHAPv2) wired connection using only terminal (no GUI)

Tags: networking, command-line

Anyone has an idea how can i do this on Ubuntu 14.04 with no GUI installed? The connection uses simple user<->password authentication and no verify certificate.

Comment: Just in case anyone has the same problem i found a solution/workaround. Just edited the file for the network adapter i was using in `/etc/NetowrkManager/system-connection` where I added the password and also configured it to auto-connect:
`password=PASS_PHRASE
system-ca-certs=false`

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to use the cli client for network-manager:

```
# Get list of connections
nmcli c list
nmcli c up <connection_id>
```